# Running Airflow DAG on Tuesday 00:00:00 every week

Tags: airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run a DAG on Airflow (GCP Cloud Composer to be exact) on weekly bases.
But the Dag is not ran on Tuesdays as I'm specifying on the Cron expression.

In all the examples I found the schedule_interval was sat as an interval (daily,weekly, and so on). I can't figure out what the error might be on my settings.

```
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('07/08/2020 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'),
    'depends_on_past':False,
    'catchup' :...,
    'retry_delay': ...,
    'project_id': ...
}
with models.DAG(
        'every_Tues_00_00',
        schedule_interval= "0 0 * * 2",
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
.
.
.
```

Comment: Is your scheduler running ? Are other dags triggering as you coded ? Also check this param in your DAG schedule_interval. Let me know.

Comment: In addition to the information requested by @Ademi, could you provide the following additional information on the current behavior of your DAG?

- Since the day you uploaded your code, did you leave your DAG running?

- If so, more than a week has passed and it has not been re-execute again?

Comment: Fellows, I'm very sorry for the late response, I'm working as a contractor with next to no permissions. I finally got access to the Composer monitoring dashboard, "Metric is not available" is displayed in the Scheduler heartbeat. However daily scheduled Dags run as expected, while weekly Dags don't, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind is when Airflow triggers the task.

"For example, if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2020-01-01 will be triggered soon after 2020-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended. The execution_date available in the context will also be 2020-01-01." [1]

[1] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html